# Flask app not deploying dependencies via Travis CI

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github, flask, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy my simple Flask app ([github.com/borao/units](https://github.com/borao/units)) to Google App Engine via Travis CI, but none of the dependencies are installing. If I deploy manually via command line, lib folders and info-egg show as existing, but the Travis CI deployment simply doesn't include those critical resources. Below is my .travis.yml. Forgive me for simple mistakes- I'm a student and haven't quite figured out CI yet.

```
language: python
python:
- "2.7"

before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_3a135b8df491_key -iv $encrypted_3a135b8df491_iv -in client-secret.json.enc -out client-secret.json -d

-install:       
- pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt

script:
- echo "No Script to run"

deploy:
  provider: gae
  skip_cleanup: true
  keyfile: "client-secret.json"
  project: "boraware-161305"
```

The build shows as passing, probably because I'm not testing properly. So I don't know that there's a problem until I go to the website and refresh. How do I get Travis CI to tell me and fail the build?

Essential question: I know I'm installing Flask (and dependencies?) for testing, but how do I get it to ship to GAE?